# Como usar async / await - vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async

estoy tratando de entender como implementar el async/await, entiendo su concepto y lo que hace. Lo que quiero lograr
es que se termine de ejecuta el metodo de mi store this.setIdentificacion(inputIdentificacion), luego de ese set ,
ejecutar una peticion, obviamente para realizar la peticion tiene que estar seteada la identificacion. Pero no logro
realizarlo correctamente. EN si sirve todo perfectamente, pero quiero hacerlo asi porque logicamente tiene que haber seteado una
identificacion para poder hacer una peticion. Como podria realizarlo paso por paso, esperando los dos segundos del setTImeOut. espero
una guia por favor. Gracias

componente boton

```
methods: {

 async $_validateRequestVisit(){
 await this.setIdentificacion(inputIdentificacion)
             
          await this.getDataCustomer()
}

}
```

store index.js

```
mutations:{
       
       async setIdentificacion (state,payload){

            setTimeout(()=>{
               state.dataContacto.identificacion =  payload
                console.log( state.dataContacto.identificacion)
            },2222)
          
        },
   
    }, actions:{
```

async getDataCustomer({commit,state,dispatch}){

```
    try {
       
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('datoIngresadoABuscar',state.dataContacto.identificacion)

        const res = await axios.post(API_BASE_URL+'controllers/equipoController.php?equipo=ver',
        form )
        const dataDB = await res.data 
       
        if(!dataDB[0].result){
          
            commit('mostrarLoaderVisita',false)

            state.error.tipo = 'cliente_inexistente'
            state.error.message = 'Identificacio no encontrada'
            state.error.alert = 'alert-danger'

            setTimeout(() =>{

                state.error.tipo = null
                state.error.message = null
                state.error.alert = null

            },3000)

            return

        }else{

        // ------LIMPIO ERRORES--------
            state.error.tipo = null
            state.error.message = null
            state.error.alert = null
        // ------END LIMPIO ERRORES----

        dispatch('processContact',dataDB)

        }

    
    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error)
        commit('mostrarLoaderVisita',false)
        
    }

     // commit('completarDatos')


   
},
```

Comment: Todo esto que estas pidiendo, esta explicitamente explicado en la documentacion... lo viste? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-must-be-synchronous

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi Muy util

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el store, debes usar (en vez de callbacks) promesas que son los que el async/await utiliza internamente, basicamente lo que esta pasando es que el callback se esta ejecutando y el async/await al detectar que nada esta esperando (no hay ninguna promesa ejecutandose) sigue pasando y dice... **Aqui no ha pasado nada! Continuemos...**, lo que puedes hacer es crear una promesa basada en el `setTimeout` de javascript. Archivo del store:

```js
    setIdentificacion (state,payload){

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Se crea una promesa! el resolve es el que avisa al await de que deje de esperar
            state.dataContacto.identificacion = payload
            console.log(state.dataContacto.identificacion)
            // luego dices que ya termino
            resolve()
        });
    },
```

Y al ejecutar esto:

```js
await this.setIdentificacion(inputIdentificacion) // -> Aqui espera a que el metodo llame al resolve()
// Aqui se lleno la data con el setTimeout (promesa)
await this.getDataCustomer() // -> Empezo el proceso de la base de datos
```

Comment: Gracias alpha. Entendi.

Comment: El problema no es este. Las mutaciones son sincronicas, las actions son asincronicas. Moviendo su codigo a un action se soluciona todo. Esta todo explicado en la documentacion que le pase.

Comment: Es cierto pero, basandonos en la forma que el lo esta haciendo (con un setTimeout) se puede solucionar de esa manera (usando las promesas para hacerlo compatible y funcional con async/await)

Comment: @gbianchi las actions del store son asincronas por defecto?

Comment: @Alpha lo probaste? yo nunca lo probe porque la documentacion dice explicitamente que no funciona... que se tiene que hacer en un action...

Comment: @AlvaroAliaga en las actions podes poner todo el codigo asincronico que quieras, sin problemas....